# how to improve a simple network

Tags: keras

I am starting to play with Keras and simple neural networks. The question is about correctness and what are the next steps to improve the accuracy.

Considering the dataset in http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/default+of+credit+card+clients
which has 30K examples and 24 features with the goal of predicting if there will be a default or not. I created a simple net with 24 input sources in the input layer, 16 hidden, and a final softmax layer. Loss is binary_crossentropy. Test is 10% and validation_split is 20%

One input line is

```
1,20000,2,2,1,24,2,2,-1,-1,-2,-2,3913,3102,689,0,0,0,0,689,0,0,0,0,1
```

Code is

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils

# load training in a panda dataframe and skip first line
train = pd.read_csv('./data/defaulCC.csv', header=1)
# split X, y
X = train.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = train.iloc[:,-1:].values
dimof_input = X.shape[1]
dimof_output = len(set(y.flat))
print('dimof_input: ', dimof_input)
print('dimof_output: ', dimof_output)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.9, random_state=0)
y_train, y_test = [np_utils.to_categorical(x) for x in (y_train, y_test)]
print X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape

# Set constants
batch_size = 128
dimof_middle = 16
dropout = 0.2
countof_epoch = 100
verbose = 1
optimizer='sgd'

print('batch_size: ', batch_size)
print('dimof_middle: ', dimof_middle)
print('dropout: ', dropout)
print('countof_epoch: ', countof_epoch)
print('verbose: ', verbose)
print ('optimizer: ', optimizer)

# this network has dimof_input n the input layer
# dimof_output in the output layer
# dimof_middle in the hidden layer

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dimof_middle, input_dim=dimof_input, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
#model.add(Dense(dimof_middle, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(dimof_output, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train
model.fit(
X_train, y_train,
validation_split=0.2,
batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=countof_epoch, verbose=verbose)

# Evaluate
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=verbose)
print('loss: ', loss)
print('accuracy: ', accuracy)
print()
```

Output is

```
Using Theano backend.
('dimof_input: ', 24)
('dimof_output: ', 2)
(27000, 24) (3000, 24) (27000, 2) (3000, 2)
('batch_size: ', 128)
('dimof_middle: ', 16)
('dropout: ', 0.2)
('countof_epoch: ', 100)
('verbose: ', 1)
('optimizer: ', 'sgd')
Train on 27000 samples, validate on 5400 samples
Epoch 1/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.6371 - acc: 0.7727 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 2/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5866 - acc: 0.7757 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 3/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.6024 - acc: 0.7750 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 4/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5859 - acc: 0.7758 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 5/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5854 - acc: 0.7761 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 6/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5883 - acc: 0.7760 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 7/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5855 - acc: 0.7761 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 8/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5854 - acc: 0.7761 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 9/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5847 - acc: 0.7762 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 10/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5900 - acc: 0.7760 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 11/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5689 - acc: 0.7773 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 12/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5665 - acc: 0.7775 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 13/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5653 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 14/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5701 - acc: 0.7773 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 15/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5582 - acc: 0.7780 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 16/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5682 - acc: 0.7774 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 17/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5665 - acc: 0.7775 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 18/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5648 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 19/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5636 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 20/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5700 - acc: 0.7772 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 21/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5597 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 22/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5597 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 23/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 24/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5590 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 25/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5573 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 26/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5590 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 27/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5621 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 28/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5581 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 29/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5576 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 30/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5590 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 31/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5575 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 32/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5598 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 33/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5604 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 34/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5609 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 35/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5598 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 36/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5575 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 37/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5592 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 38/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 39/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5637 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 40/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 41/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5584 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 42/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5564 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 43/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 44/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5576 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 45/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 46/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5595 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 47/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5581 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 48/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5598 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 49/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5576 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 50/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5610 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 51/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5616 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 52/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5598 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 53/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5569 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 54/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5589 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 55/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5569 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 56/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5563 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 57/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5598 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 58/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5607 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 59/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5611 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 60/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5558 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 61/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5620 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 62/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5592 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 63/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5608 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 64/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5587 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 65/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5586 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 66/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5608 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 67/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5605 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 68/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5598 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 69/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5621 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 70/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5607 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 71/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5609 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 72/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 73/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5586 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 74/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5603 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 75/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5625 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 76/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5573 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 77/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5590 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 78/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5608 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 79/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5613 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 80/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5564 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 81/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5638 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 82/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5609 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 83/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5591 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 84/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5599 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 85/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5615 - acc: 0.7776 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 86/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5616 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 87/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5616 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 88/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5586 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 89/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5615 - acc: 0.7777 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 90/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5581 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 91/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5580 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 92/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5586 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 93/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5611 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 94/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5589 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 95/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5595 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 96/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5623 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 97/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5623 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 98/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5605 - acc: 0.7779 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 99/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5612 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
Epoch 100/100
27000/27000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5612 - acc: 0.7778 - val_loss: 3.6157 - val_acc: 0.7744
3000/3000 [==============================] - 0s     
('loss: ', 3.4197844168345135)
('accuracy: ', 0.78666666682561237)
()
```

Answer (score 1):

The loss is not decreasing and that is a problem. There are several you can do to improve:

- Normalize your data. In your specific example all features have different ranges, so normalizing them is a must for a neural network to learn successfully. To normalize you can compute the mean and standard deviation of each feature, and subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation, this will leave features in an approximate [-1, 1] range. Min-Max normalization should also work.
- After normalizing, you can increase your model's capacity by adding more layers. You could also try using different non-linearities like sigmoid.
- Increase regularization. You are using Dropout with p = 0.2, and you could increase it to p = 0.5. Alternatively you could use Batch Normalization.

This answer is pretty generic but this advice should work with many kinds of data.